# Xcode 5, how to redirect console output to file

Tags: xcode, debugging

Currently, I use NSLog to print out all most of messages in Xcode 5, and sometimes there are lots methods called. I'm wondering whether there is "easy" ways to redirect all the console output to a file

Answer (score 1):

Best way is use some logger, you can write one by self or use for example CocoaLumberjack is  easy to install end config with rich functional.

[Github CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack)

PS. If you prefer not use third party code, create your own logger and make makro with `NSLog` name and your function inside.